# Hibernate ManyToMany with JoinTable delete propagation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following property defined:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "person_unit", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "unit_id") })
    private Set<OrgUnit> units;

}
```

Which refences the `OrgUnit` class, that is defined as:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "orgunit", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "parentunit_id", "name" }) })
public class OrgUnit extends AbstractEntity {
  ...
}
```

Now, when I try to delete a `Person`, it should only remove the rows from the `person` and `person_unit` tables. But instead Hibernate seems to try to remove the linked `OrgUnit` as well, because I get the following error message:

```
2011-12-02 10:52:30,527 WARN  [ajp-2009-2] JDBCExceptionReporter: SQL Error: 547, SQLState: 23000
2011-12-02 10:52:30,527 ERROR [ajp-2009-2] JDBCExceptionReporter: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint 'FKE6A2C42EB024FBA5'. The conflict occured in database TEST, table 'TEST.person_unit', column 'unit_id'.
2011-12-02 10:52:30,527 ERROR [ajp-2009-2] AbstractFlushingEventListener: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [<-- snip -->.server.entities.OrgUnit#337]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2712)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2895)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
    at <-- snip -->.server.controller.PersonController.deletePerson(PersonController.java:60)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it propagates the deletion because you told it to do it with

```
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
```

`ALL` includes `REMOVE`. It should never be used on ManyToXxx associations.